# Assigning map of slices in a struct in Golang

Tags: go, struct, slice

How to correctly assign a map of slices to a struct in Golang?
I tried to following, but it does not work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    name     string
    testCase map[string][]string
}

var t = Test{
    name: "myTest",
    testCase: map[string][]string{"key": {"value1", "value2"}}
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

.\main.go:14:61: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or }

Comment: `testCase: map[string][]string{"key":{"value1", "value2"}}`

Comment: No, still does not work.

Comment: understand the error message, missing a trailing `,`. Add it

Comment: Got it, thanks. Didn't expect that, because there was nothing following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add its type as a prefix when you assign the value.

```
type Test struct {
    name     string
    testCase map[string][]string
}

var t = Test{
    name: "myTest",
    testCase: map[string][]string{
        "key": {"value1", "value2"},
    },
}
```

> Don't forget to add comma separator at the end of the item, since its
> use vertical style map

[Reference](https://gobyexample.com/maps)